# Is it possible to run google map api in phonegap?

Tags: cordova, google-maps

I am building an app with apache cordava(Phonegap). My question is, can I run google map api in that? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can run googlemaps api in your phonegap/cordova application.First you need to get an api key (browser based and not android one). 
Start out by generating your API_KEY and use that .

Then u need to whitelist the URL , Here is a simple index.html which loads up the map with a marker.
Hope it Helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' https://maps.googleapis.com/ https://maps.gstatic.com/ https://mts0.googleapis.com/ 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
<style>
    body, html, #map {  margin: 0;width:100%;height:400px }
#map {
    position: relative;
    width:400px;
    height: :50%;
}

#map:after {
    width: 22px;
    height: 40px;
    display: block;
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; left: 50%;
    margin: -40px 0 0 -11px;
    background: url('https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/spotlight-poi_hdpi.png');
    background-size: 22px 40px;  
   pointer-events: none; 
}

    </style>



   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initialize" async defer></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        function initialize() {
          var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 4,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33, 151),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
          };
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
        }



    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>

  </body>
</html>
```

You can read more about googlemaps api in here

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple
```

you can read about creating api key in here

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key
```

Comment: let me try this and will let you know @IamKarim